# Vue + Jest fails if directory renamed

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Has anybody else seen this? I'm using Vue 3.0.5 on Ubuntu 18.04. I created a project,

```
vue create jest-example
```

I used the defaults except for adding unit tests and selecting jest.

```
cd jest-example
npm run test:unit
```

The sample test runs and passes.

```
cd ..
mv jest-example something
cd something
npm run test:unit

Jest encountered an unexpected token
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^
```

Change it back to the original directory name

```
cd ..
mv something jest-example
cd jest-example
npm run test:unit
```

And the test passes again. Why would renaming the directory cause the unit tests to no longer work?

I tried removing the node_modules directory and that didn't matter.

Comment: Have you tried updating the CLI? The latest version is `v3.4.1`

Comment: I just updated to 3.4.1. Same behavior.I hit this trying to add jest to an existing project, so I have a bit of a workaround. It's just weird that it behaves this way. If I add all the jest stuff to my project, it gives the unexpected token errors. If I create a new project, delete all the files in that project and copy over all my existing stuff, it works.